# What references do I need for SPWeb?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have this code to upload attachment.

```
using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.AllWebs["webname"])
{
  SPList list = web.Lists["Custom List"];
  SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
  item["Title"] = "New List Item";

  SPAttachmentCollection attachments = item.Attachments;
  attachments.Add(fileName, byteArrayContents);

  item.Update();
}
```

However, I am not sure where can i get the `SPList` and `SPWeb` classes ? 
How can I add these references ?

**EDIT : let me rephrase my question. I was aware of `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared` . The problem is that there is no `web server extensions` folder there.**

Is it possible that it could be anywhere else ?

Comment: Try searching like so: "MSDN SPWeb" (the "MSDN" part is important, and most Microsoft class references can be found trivially as such). You'll need to get the *non-distributable* `Microsoft.SharePoint` assembly (as indicated by the MSDN documentation) from a real SP environment - I encourage using a SP development environment. SP clients are encouraged to use the *Client Object Model* instead.

Comment: Look at this [SPWeb class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.aspx) and this [SPList class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have SharePoint installed on the same machine where you are doing your development. Microsoft do not allow redistribution of the DLLs that comprise SharePoint. The reason you don't have a "web server extensions" folder is because you don't have SharePoint installed.

So, good news though: You can install the "lite" version from here - http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=24983

This is the SharePoint Foundation 2010 download. You might want the 2007 version, in which case the download is for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 (wss 3.0). Also, a new 2013 version is available, known as SharePoint Foundation 2013.

I trust you know which version you need.

Answer (score 5):

You need the `Microsoft.SharePoint` dll. This can be found here:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\(Number varies on your version of SharePoint)\ISAPI\

Then add `using Microsoft.SharePoint`.

Reference for [SPWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.aspx) and [SPList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.aspx)

Comment: +1 Thank you. However I do not have this `web server extensions` folder

Comment: I can go as far as `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\` and there are ten subfolders in here . I check each of them and could not find anything like Microdoft.Sharepoint.dll

Comment: @AndreiVasilev Do you have the IIS role installed? Do you have SharePoint installed? What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Yes I do. I use it as a client . version 2010 . I do NOT have SP server installed though

Comment: The only _supported_ way to develop server-side solutions for SharePoint is to have it installed locally. The license does not allow redistribution of the runtime DLLs, except for the SharePoint Client libraries, which do not seem to be the ones you need.